# list of list i want to change exactly one component

Tags: python, list

in 19x19 matrix with all `components == 0` now (list of list a)

for example, i want to change `a[1][1]` to `1`

but they changed all index(1) of lists of list(a)

*emphasized text* tried to stop using for- sentence and changed to while-, just typed several times not using loops.

```
a = []

row = []

for i in range(19) :
    row.append(0)

for i in range(19) :
    a.append(row)

#19x19 matrix a has been made

n = int(input())

for j in range(n) :
    x, y = map(int, input().split())
    a[x-1][y-1] = 1


for k in a :
    print(k)
```

Comment: you are using same reference of row to append to a.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding the same row again and again.

```py
a = []

row = []

for i in range(19) :
    row.append(0)

for i in range(19) :
    a.append(row[:])    #slice it to make a copy
```

Comment: Just thinking, it might be more helpful for OP to understand the concept if you can add some explanation to why they are the same row.

Comment: thanks !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!